# Extract multiple strings from a multiple lines text file

Tags: awk

How to extract multiple strings from a multiple lines text file with these rules?
The search strings are "String server", " pac " and "String method".
They may or may not appear only once within the enclosing "{}".
After the search strings are matched, extract their values enclosed within "" without "()".
The value of either search string "String server" or " pac " appear only once - no duplication.
Its value will appear before the value of the search string "String method".
e.g. sample text file
in:

```
public AResponse retrieveA(ARequest req){
    String server = "AAA";
    String method =  "retrieveA()";
    log.info(method,
            server,
            req);
    return res;
}

public BResponse retrieveB(BRequest req){
    String method =  "retrieveB()";
    BBB pac = new BBB();
    log.info(method,
            pac,
            req);
    return res;
}

public CResponse retrieveC(CRequest req) {
    String server = "CCC";
    log.info(server,
            req);
    return res;
}

public DResponse retrieveD(DRequest req) {
    String method = "retrieveD()";
    log.info(method,req);
    return res;
}

public EResponse retrieveE(ERequest req){
    EEE pac = new EEE();
    String method =  "retrieveE()";
    String server = "EEE";
    log.info(method,
            server,
            pac,
            req);
    return res;
}
```

Expected output:

```
AAA retrieveA
BBB retrieveB
CCC 
retrieveD
EEE retrieveE
```

I tried GNU Awk 5.0.1:

```
awk '{
if ($0 ~ /String method/ || ($0 ~ /String server/) ) 
{
str=$0; 
sub("String", "", str);
sub(")", "", str);
sub("=", "", str);
gsub(/\(/, "", str);
gsub(/"/, "", str);
gsub(/;/, "", str);
if (str ~ /method/) 
{
    method = str; 
    gsub(/[[:blank:]]/, "", method); 
    gsub(/method/, "", method); 
    arr[i][1] = method
    count++
} else if (str ~ /server/) 
{
    server = str; 
    gsub(/[[:blank:]]/, "", server); 
    gsub(/server/, "", server); 
    arr[i][0] = server
    count++
}
}
if (count > 1 || $0 ~ /log./) {
    count = 0
    i++
}
}
END {
for (i in arr) {
    printf "%s %s\n", arr[i][0], arr[i][1];
}
}' in
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `awk` solution should work for you:

```bash
awk -v OFS='\t' -F= '
/\{[[:blank:]]*$/ {++n}
NF==2 && /String | pac/ {
   gsub(/^[[:blank:]]*("|new +)|[()";]+$/, "", $2)
   if ($1 ~ / (server|pac)/)
      col1[n] = $2
   else if ($1 ~ / method/)
      col2[n] = $2
}
END {
   for (i=1; i<=n; ++i)
      print col1[i], col2[i]
}' file

AAA     retrieveA
BBB     retrieveB
CCC
        retrieveD
EEE     retrieveE
```

Comment: @ anubhava, Your solution works! However, testing with a slightly larger file does not work with the new data, do I post a new question?

Comment: Yes please post.a new question with additional data and details. You may accept this solution that worked for the currently posted problem

Answer (score 1):

This one too, should work with your file (not sure if I considered all possible variants...)

```
$ cat test.awk 
$1 == "String" {
  if ($2 == "server") {
    first = $4" "
  } else if ($2 == "method") {
    second = $4
  }
}

$2 == "pac" {
    first   = $1" "
}

$1 == "return" {
  print first second
  first=""; second=""
}
```

---

```
$ awk -f test.awk file | tr -d '"();'
AAA retrieveA
BBB retrieveB
CCC 
retrieveD
EEE retrieveE
```

Where the awk script, when finding the string "String" in 1st position, checks the 2nd position: if it's "server" then saves the 4th position in `first` variable, otherwise, if it's "method" saves the 4th position in `second` variable. Then, going on, in case of "pac" string in 2nd position it saves the 1st position again in `first` variable: in this case only one between "pac" and "String server" is considered. Finally, when it finds the string "return" (hoping it's always at the end of each "public" block ...) it prints out the 2 variables (valued or not) saved before.
The piped final tr is to delete eventual remaining character `"();` (here too, I don't know if that chars can be part of the other values to keep...).

I know, a bit too many concerns in my answer. I hope it can help you anyway.

Comment: Your solution is missing "retrieveD" when I test it.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry @albertkao9. Maybe is there some case-different letter in your actual file? Maybe it's just a matter of put a `BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1};` directive at the beginning of awk script? I tested with your posted file content with GNU Awk 5.2.1 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1 using [TXR](https://nongnu.org/txr):

The sample data is in the file `data`:

```
$ txr extract.txr data
AAA retrieveA
BBB retrieveB
CCC
retrieveD
EEE retrieveE
```

In `extract.txr` we have:

```
@(repeat)
@  (cases)
 String server = "@x";
 String method = "@y()";
@    (bind out `@x @y`)
@  (or)
 String method = "@y()";
 @x pac = new @x();
@    (bind out `@x @y`)
@  (or)
 @x pac = new @x();
 String method = "@y()";
@    (bind out `@x @y`)
@  (or)
 String server = "@out";
@  (or)
 String method = "@out()";
@  (end)
@  (skip)
}
@  (do (put-line out))
@(end)
```

In TXR, one space implicitly matches one or more spaces, so the patterns need only one space of indentation, and the extra whitespace in `method =  "retrieveB()"` does not appear. The `data` is exactly as given, with the extra whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 2 using [TXR](https://nongnu.org/txr):

The sample data is in the file `data`:

```
$ txr extract2.txr data
AAA retrieveA
BBB retrieveB
CCC
retrieveD
EEE retrieveE
```

In `extract2.txr` we have:

```
@(repeat)
public @nil{
@  (gather :vars ((server nil) (meth nil) (pac nil)))
 String server = "@server";
 String method = "@meth()";
 @pac pac = new @pac();
@  (until)
}
@  (end)
@  (do
     (put-line
       (cond
         ((and server meth) `@server @meth`)
         ((and meth pac) `@pac @meth`)
         (server)
         (meth))))
@(end)
```

In solution 2 we take advantage of the [`@(gather)`](https://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-727D63B1) directive, which collects matches that may be out of order. In each function block we gather up to three items. They may be missing, so we default them to [`nil`](https://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#S-4D33C2A5) via `:vars`; that allows `gather` to succeed even if some of the items are missing, with those default values. Note [`nil`](https://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#S-4D33C2A5) is false in TXR Lisp; the missing items look false.

After the `gather` block, we do a bit of Lisp to test which variables we have in a [`cond`](https://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-37EA722C) form, to calculate an output string that is output via [`put-line`](https://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#S-2E907EFD).

We take advantage of a somewhat rarely-used feature of `cond` (which is also present in ANSI Common Lisp) which is that if a `cond` clause contains only one expression, and that expression is true (so that `cond` stops  there), the value of that expression is the result of `cond`, such that `(cond (1))` yields `1`: `1` is both the true expression that terminates the conditional, **and** serves as the result value.