# Extract multiple strings from a multiple lines text file - larger test file

Tags: awk

How to extract multiple strings from a multiple lines text file with these rules?
The search strings are "String server", " pac " and "String method".
They may or may not appear only once within the enclosing "{}".
After the search strings are matched, extract their values enclosed within "" without "()".
The value of either search string "String server" or " pac " appear only once - no duplication.
Its value will appear before the value of the search string "String method".
e.g. sample text file
in:

```
{{{{{
public AResponse retrieveA(ARequest req){
    String server = "AAA";
    String method =  "retrieveA()";
    log.info(method,
            server,
            req);
    return res;
}

public BResponse retrieveB(BRequest req){
    String method =  "retrieveB()";
    BBB pac = new BBB();
    log.info(method,
            pac,
            req);
    return res;
}

public CResponse retrieveC(CRequest req) {
    String server = "CCC";
    log.info(server,
            req);
    return res;
}

public DResponse retrieveD(DRequest req) {
    String method = "retrieveD()";
    log.info(method,req);
    return res;
}

public EResponse retrieveE(ERequest req){
    EEE pac = new EEE();
    String method =  "retrieveE()";
    String server = "EEE";
    log.info(method,
            server,
            pac,
            req);
    return res;
}

public FResponse callretrieveF(FRequest req) throws InvalidDataException {
        String server = "FFFFF";
        //retrieveF
        String method =  "retrieveF()";
        try {
            log.info(method,
                     server,
                     req);

            FFFFF pac = new FFFFF();
        }
}

/**
 * callgetG
* getG
*/
public GResponse callgetG(GRequest req) throws InvalidDataException {
        //getG
        String method =  "getG()";
        String server = "GGGGGG";
        try {
            try {
                GGGGGG pac = new GGGGGG();
                log.info(method,
                     server,
                     req);
            }
        }
}

/**
 * getH
*/
    public HResponse getH(HRequest req) 
                                throws InvalidDataException {

        //getH
        String method =  "getH()";
        String server = "HHHHHHH";
        String calledMethod =  "getH2()";

        ARequest aReq = new ARequest(req.getH(),
                                     req.getR());
        ProgramAccountInformationResponse resp = null;
        try {
            log.info(LogMessages.msgInfoMethodStartPrivate(method,
                                                           server,
                                                           calledMethod,
                                                           req));
            return resp;
        }catch(InvalidDataException ide){
            log.error(method);
            throw ide;
        }
    }

}}}}}
```

Expected output:

```
AAA retrieveA
BBB retrieveB
CCC 
retrieveD
EEE retrieveE
FFFFF retrieveF
GGGGGG getG
HHHHHHH getH
```

I tried the solution from:
[Extract multiple strings from a multiple lines text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78239257/extract-multiple-strings-from-a-multiple-lines-text-file)

```
awk -v OFS='\t' -F= '
/\{[[:blank:]]*$/ {++n}
NF==2 && /String | pac/ {
   gsub(/^[[:blank:]]*("|new +)|[()";]+$/, "", $2)
   if ($1 ~ / (server|pac)/)
      col1[n] = $2
   else if ($1 ~ / method/)
      col2[n] = $2
}
END {
   for (i=1; i<=n; ++i)
      print col1[i], col2[i]
}' in
```

Comment: Your sample input isn't adequate to test a potential solution as it only contains the sunny day cases where the strings you want to match are the only ones that could match the most obvious regexps. Given that, you're likely to get solutions that will only work for the sunny day cases but then fail on your real data. Consider comments and or strings that contain `String server = "GGGGGG";`, superstrings like `pacific`, white space around tokens like `;`, etc.

Comment: Please make an attempt to write your own code to solve your problems rather than just copying the answer from your previous question into your new one.[edit] your question to show your attempt to solve the problem yourself so we can help you with that and we get an indication you're learning from your previous questions rather than just asking for code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try a modified version of the previous awk script here.

```bash
cat parse.awk

BEGIN { OFS="\t"; FS="=" }
/^[[:blank:]]*public / {++n}
NF==2 && /^[[:blank:]]*String | pac *=/ {
   gsub(/^[[:blank:]]*("|new +)|[()";]+$/, "", $2)
   if ($1 ~ / (server|pac)/)
      col1[n] = $2
   else if ($1 ~ / method/)
      col2[n] = $2
}
END {
   for (i=1; i<=n; ++i)
      print col1[i], col2[i]
}
```

Then use it as:

```bash
awk -f parse.awk file

AAA     retrieveA
BBB     retrieveB
CCC
        retrieveD
EEE     retrieveE
FFFFF   retrieveF
GGGGGG  getG
HHHHHHH getH
```

Comment: @ anubhava, Your modified solution works again! Thanks!!! However, testing with a slightly larger file again does not work, I am trying to find out why and may post a new question.

Comment: Made few checks to make it bit more precise but of course it can be improved further seeing more complex data.

Comment: I post a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78248071/extract-multiple-strings-from-a-multiple-lines-text-file-an-extra-rule-and-lar .  Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like the OPs just going to be asking you for more and more code as they figure out what their real input looks like.

Answer (score 0):

A minor change to the [TXR](https://nongnu.org/txr) solutions handles it:

```
$ txr extract2.txr longer-data
AAA retrieveA
BBB retrieveB
CCC
retrieveD
EEE retrieveE
FFFFF retrieveF
GGGGGG getG
HHHHHHH getH
```

Code:

```
@(repeat)
@(freeform 2)
@/ */public@nil{
@  (gather :vars ((server nil) (meth nil) (pac nil)))
 String server = "@server";
 String method = "@meth()";
 @pac pac = new @pac();
@  (until)
@/ */}
@  (end)
@  (do
     (put-line
       (cond
         ((and server meth) `@server @meth`)
         ((and meth pac) `@pac @meth`)
         (server)
         (meth))))
@(end)
```

A key detail is the `@(freeform 2)` which instructs TXR to treat the next two lines as if they were one line (with embedded `\n` characters), then match into them. Any unmatched material is divided back into multiple lines and pushed back into the input. This easily handles the `public ...` function header that is split across two lines. We recognize some optional spaces since there is an occurrence of `public` not in the first column, and also a closing brace not in the first column.

I see that the indentation matches: the curly brace which closes each function is aligned with the `public`.  We could make the matching stricter so that we match a closing brace which is at the same indentation as `public`, and not just any curly brace.

This doesn't change the output, but is good to know about:

```
@(repeat)
@(freeform 2)
@{indent / */}public@nil{
@  (gather :vars ((server nil) (meth nil) (pac nil)))
 String server = "@server";
 String method = "@meth()";
 @pac pac = new @pac();
@  (until)
@indent}
@  (end)
@  (do
     (put-line
       (cond
         ((and server meth) `@server @meth`)
         ((and meth pac) `@pac @meth`)
         (server)
         (meth))))
@(end)
```

By changing the regex match `@/ */` (one or more spaces) to `@{indent / */}`, we capture that indentation into the `indent` variable. Later when we mention the `@indent` variable, it has to match exactly the same text: same number of spaces.

Thus if we had a situation like this, it would still work:

```
        String method =  "getH()";
        if (whatever) {
          // ...
        }
        String server = "HHHHHHH";
        String calledMethod =  "getH2()";
```

It wouldn't think that the closing brace of the `if` is the end of the function, and pick up the `server` variable.

In the first place, we don't have to look for closing braces; that's just a decision I made. Since the functions all start with `public`, we could use the presence of `public` as a section delimiter:

```
@(repeat)
@/.*public.*/
@  (gather :vars ((server nil) (meth nil) (pac nil)))
 String server = "@server";
 String method = "@meth()";
 @pac pac = new @pac();
@  (until)
@/.*public.*/
@  (end)
@  (do
     (put-line
       (cond
         ((and server meth) `@server @meth`)
         ((and meth pac) `@pac @meth`)
         (server)
         (meth))))
@(end)
```

Comment: I am learning awk, which is preinstalled with Linux mint and Windows git bash.
I do not know txr.

Answer (score -1):

Since I was not so versed at awk, I tried python for the job. Interestingly I need much more code than in awk. But it delivers the requested output and is readable. Though it still can be improved in style and campactness. Btw it seems you don't need the keyword "pac".

```
'''
parses the file input.txt in the same path
as this python file parser.py
and extracts keywords and values
'''
import pathlib
import re
kw = ["String server", " pac ", "String method"] #list of keywords

def extract_AAA(input_str):
    match_res = None
    keyword = "[A-Z]{3}"
    match_res = re.search(keyword, input_str)
    if match_res:
        start = match_res.span()[0]
        end = match_res.span()[1]
        #extract retrieveA...D, AAA...DDD
        return match_res.string[start:end]
    return match_res

def extract_retrieve(input_str):
    match_res = None
    keyword = "retrieve[A-Z]{1}"
    match_res = re.search(keyword, input_str)
    if match_res:
        start = match_res.span()[0]
        end = match_res.span()[1]
        #extract retrieveA...D, AAA...DDD
        return match_res.string[start:end]
    return match_res

def write_to_output_AAA(res_AAA):
    fout = open("output.txt", 'a')
    fout.write(res_AAA + " ")
    fout.close()

def write_to_output_retr(res_retr):
    fout = open("output.txt", 'a')
    fout.write(res_retr + "\n")
    fout.close()

def write_newline():
    fout = open("output.txt", 'a')
    fout.write("\n")
    fout.close()

path = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve()
print(path)
finput = open("input.txt")
lines = finput.readlines()

def find_a_keyword(n):
    j = 0
    for keyword in kw:
        j = lines[n].find(keyword)
        if j >= 0:
            return j
    return j 

i = 0
#for i in range(len(lines) - 1):
while(i < len(lines) - 2):
    res_AAA = None
    res_retr = None
    if find_a_keyword(i) >= 0:
        res_AAA = extract_AAA(lines[i])
        res_retr = extract_retrieve(lines[i])
        if res_AAA:
            write_to_output_AAA(res_AAA)
            if find_a_keyword(i+1) >= 0:
                res_retr = extract_retrieve(lines[i+1])
                if res_retr:
                    write_to_output_retr(res_retr)
                    #special case: a third line with AAA - ZZZ
                    if  ( (find_a_keyword(i+1) >= 0 ) 
                            and
                            (
                                (extract_retrieve(lines[i+2]) != None) 
                                or 
                                (extract_AAA(lines[i+2]) != None)
                            )
                        ):
                        i += 3
                    else:
                        i += 2
                    continue
                else:
                    write_newline()
                    i += 1
                    continue
                continue
            else:
                write_newline()
                i += 1
                continue
            continue
        elif res_retr: #find_a_keyword(i + 1) >= 0:
            res_AAA = extract_AAA(lines[i+1])
            if res_AAA:
                write_to_output_AAA(res_AAA)
                write_to_output_retr(res_retr)
                i += 2
                continue
            else:
                write_to_output_retr(res_retr)
                i += 1
                continue
        else:
            continue
            i += 1
    else:
        i += 1
```

Comment: Sorry, copy and paste. I've corrected it. Thanks.